# i'm trying to create trigger in sql server and i'm getting error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'."

Tags: sql-server

i want to insert data in user from table Aspnetusers but i'm getting this error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user' i don't know where is the problem with the code

```
create trigger insertdata
ON AspNetUsers
After Insert
as
begin
declare
@userid int,
@userfname nvarchar(50),
@userlname nvarchar(50),
@Usermail nvarchar(50)
select @userid=ClientID,@userfname=FirstName,@userlname=LastName,@Usermail=UserName from AspNetUsers 
insert into user values(@userid,@userfname,@userlname,@Usermail)

end
go
```

Comment: Hint: `user` is a reserved keyword. Use `[user]` instead.

Comment: Ideally, rather than using `[user]` change the name of your object to something that isn't a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Also, this trigger has a major flaw, it *assumes* an `INSERT` will only ever contain one row. That is simply not true. [Bad habits to kick : abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    create trigger insertdata
    ON final
    After Insert
    as
    begin
    declare
    @userid int,
    @userfname nvarchar(50),
    @userlname nvarchar(50),
    @Usermail nvarchar(50)
    select @userid=ClientID,@userfname=FirstName,@userlname=LastName,@Usermail=UserName from AspNetUsers 
    insert into [user] values(@userid,@userfname,@userlname,@Usermail)
    end
    go
```

Comment: Could you provide any explanation?

Comment: @K Viswagna But in answer, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).